# Download file from network using PyQGIS 2.x

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt

I have a python plugin targeting QGIS 1.8 that uses [QgsNetworkAccessManager](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsNetworkAccessManager.html) and [QNetworkRequest](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html) to issue a GetCapabilities request to WMS servers.

With 1.8 everything was working fine.  Now we are porting this plugin to QGIS 2.x (tested on 2.6 and 2.7 of 16/02/2015) and have found that some errors are being displayed.

As far as our python code can tell everything is working as expected, however 20 seconds after a network request is initiated a "Network request ... timed out" message is displayed in the messages log and in a banner at the top of the map pane.

---

I have created a minimal example that can be copy/pasted into the python console:

```
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, QUrl
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest

def request_download():
    global reply
    manager = QgsNetworkAccessManager.instance()
    url = QUrl("http://www.example.net")
    request = QNetworkRequest(url)
    print "Download start time: {}".format(datetime.now())
    reply = manager.createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager.GetOperation, request)
    reply.connect(reply, SIGNAL("finished()"), handle_download)

def handle_download():
    global reply
    print "Download finish time: {}".format(datetime.now())
    print "Finished: {}".format(reply.isFinished())
    print "Bytes received: {}".format(len(reply.readAll()))

request_download()

# python console:
#   Download start time: 2015-02-23 15:24:39.887000
#   Download finish time: 2015-02-23 15:24:41.077000
#   Finished: True
#   Bytes received: 1270
# 
# message log:
#   2015-02-23T15:25:01    1    Network request http://www.example.com timed out
```

---

As this example shows the download appears to succeed:

1. The `finish()` signal is emitted.
2. The `reply.isFinished()` method returns True.
3. The `reply.readAll()` method returns the correct data.

However the time out error message is displayed :

1. Prominently on a yellow banner at the top of the map pane.
2. Under the Network tab on the Log Messages panel.

**How do I perform a download without triggering this error?**

Comment: I approached this problem month ago... I remember there wheren't solution other than popping out the message from QgsMessageBar, because the timeout was sent from a part of the qgis.core. Now I don't remember why and in what conditions there where that message (I should re-read the qgis code). I don't know if it is changed in master. Please file a issue if it can be considered an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are fine with a solution that uses `QNetworkAccessManager` from Qt (instead of the manager from QGIS libs), you can do it this way:

```
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest

def request_download(manager):
    url = QUrl("http://www.geotux.tuxfamily.org")
    request = QNetworkRequest(url)
    print "Download start time: {}".format(datetime.now())
    manager.get( request )

def handle_download(reply):
    print "Download finish time: {}".format(datetime.now())
    print "Finished: {}".format(reply.isFinished())
    print "Bytes received: {}".format(len(reply.readAll()))

manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
manager.finished.connect( handle_download )
request_download(manager)
```

As you can see, you don't need to use global variables.

---

*BTW, I couldn't use your code from a QGIS Python console, it threw this error: `RuntimeError: no access to protected functions or signals for objects not created from Python`*

Comment: Thanks, looks good I will try it out at work in the morning.

Comment: The RuntimeError surprises me, what OS and qgis version are you using?

Comment: Yes, first time I see it. QGIS v.2.8 on a GNU/Linux (Mint).

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  One gotcha I will warn readers about is that it is important that the QNetworkAccessManager instance has a lifetime that spans the duration of the network transaction.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo: And how would you manage to use the reply outside of `handle_download`? After the call `request_download` for example...

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, because you're performing an asynchronous request and you must wait until you get a response. If you write some code after the call to request_download, it will be executed right away, without waiting for the response. You would need things like this https://rohieb.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/qt-nearly-synchronous-qnetworkaccessmanager-calls/ if you really need the request/response to be synchronous.